# Encountering exception when running Batch Job

Tags: batch-processing, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am trying to run a AX 2012 batch job based on SysOperation Framework on a Live Server and encountering the following exception. Please note that the same batch job is running successfully on the staging server. I have generated full CIL to resolve this issue but no luck. Please help!

```
Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Xpp.ErrorException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Xpp.ErrorException' was thrown.
at Dynamics.Ax.Application.SysOperationController.Checkaccess() in SysOperationController.checkAccess.xpp:line 6
at Dynamics.Ax.Application.SysOperationServiceController.Checkaccess() in SysOperationServiceController.checkAccess.xpp:line 24
at Dynamics.Ax.Application.SysOperationServiceController.Unpack(Object[] packedState) in SysOperationServiceController.unpack.xpp:line 15
at Dynamics.Ax.Application.BatchRun.runJobStaticCode(Int64 batchId) in BatchRun.runJobStaticCode.xpp:line 36
at Dynamics.Ax.Application.BatchRun.runJobStatic(Int64 batchId) in BatchRun.runJobStatic.xpp:line 13
at BatchRun::runJobStatic(Object[] )
at Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Xpp.ReflectionCallHelper.MakeStaticCall(Type type, String MethodName, Object[] parameters)
at BatchIL.taskThreadEntry(Object threadArg)
```

Answer (score 1):

The X++ exception message was not shown:

> Access denied: %1

Where %1 is the name of a class.

I would try to recreate the batch job, to see if it helps. The user running the current batch job may have insufficient rights.